# .Jar File Binding Errors in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to bind `DJI-SDK.Jar` file in my Binding Library Project. When I build my project it showed me these errors

Param error when build the project

`CS1519 Invalid token 'params' in class, struct, or interface member declaration    JarBinding`'

Other error showed when I removed the Param keyword

`Error  CS0535  'ResolutionAndFrameRate' does not implement interface member 'IComparable.CompareTo(Object)'`

`Error  CS0535  'FlyforbidUtils.DataComparator' does not implement interface member 'IComparator.Compare(Object, Object)'`

`Error  CS0111  Type 'ServiceManager' already defines a member called 'Destroy' with the same parameter types`

`Error  CS0111  Type 'UsbHostServiceRC' already defines a member called 'Destroy' with the same parameter types`

`Error  CS0111  Type 'BluetoothLeService' already defines a member called 'Destroy' with the same parameter type`

`Error  CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'BluetoothLeService.Destroy()' and 'BluetoothLeService.Destroy()'`

Please help me to resolve these issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use images of the error, add the error text directly to your question

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover I updated my question with error text

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the Java generics implementation of IComparable.

You can create a Additions/your_class_name.cs that contains partial your_class class and CompareTo explicit method implementation like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace Com.Journeyapps.Barcodescanner
{
    public partial class Size
    {
        int Java.Lang.IComparable.CompareTo(Java.Lang.Object obj)
        {
            return CompareTo((Com.Journeyapps.Barcodescanner.Size)obj);
        }
    }
}
```

See this answer here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1950/binding-jar-file-with-class-that-implements-java-lang-icomparable